# Is there a cn_util implementation for python

Tags: monerod, rpc

I'am trying to implement stratum server logic in python (looking at projects like https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum/ or https://github.com/lucasjones/node-cryptonote-util/ and if wonder if there is a python implementation.

Thanks in advance,
x.

Answer (score 1):

> ...if there is a python implementation.

There's [py-cryptonight](https://pypi.org/project/py-cryptonight/) for the older POW algorithm (cryptonight) and [pyrx](https://github.com/jtgrassie/pyrx) for the *current* algorithm (RandomX). There's also example usage for these in [monero-powpy](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy).

I'm not aware of anyone that's bothered to write a Monero pool server in python, nor a version of cryptonote-util.